# How can I load a file in memory on the Apple IIGS?

Tags: graphics-programming

I recently got an Apple IIGS and have it booting GS/OS off of a compact flash with 10 32MB ProDOS volumes. It's a great little setup and I've installed ORCA/M, 816 Paint, Merlin 16+ and Complete Pascal (also known as TML Pascal II) so I can get started programming games for it.

My first goal, for now, is to just display an image on the screen that I've saved from 816 Paint. But I don't even know how to load a file as binary into memory. How can I accomplish that using Pascal and the other tools I've listed above?

Comment: Since "how do I get started" questions are off-topic here, I've edited your question to simply ask the first concrete problem you posed (loading a file into memory); you could do the same with other follow-up issues you have, posting each as a separate question. You also may want to have a look at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com if you have not already, as it may have a broader audience for working with older computers than this site does.

Comment: I think you'll have more luck hunting down people working explicitly on this platform since almost no one is programming in Turbo Pascal anymore, let alone for the Apple IIe/IIgs series. Where that is I am afraid I do not know; google groups, useness, irc maybe.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I've already posted this on comp.sys.apple2 and comp.sys.apple2.programmer, I'm just trying to get the widest coverage possible.